# Shadows working on three.js r-54 but not working on three.js r-84

Tags: three.js, shadow

I have a problem with shadows on three.js

In this scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/manumid/q5qhjkka/2/ I have a cube with a light pointing to it. It uses three.js r-54. The shadow works fine.

But in the same example, using three.js r-84: https://jsfiddle.net/manumid/krpgr0x0/ the shadow does not appear.

The only difference between codes is, besides the three.js version, the light shadow helper (although this has no relation with my shadow problem):

On r-54:
`spot.shadowCameraVisible = true;`

On r-84:
`scene.add (new THREE.CameraHelper(spot.shadow.camera));`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of props seem to have changed between those 30 versions of three. I don't have it looking exactly the same but hopefully this at least helps? A lot of the shadow and shadowMap names are in different places and spotlight has quite a lot more controls now. A good playpen to see how the properties affect the light can be found here https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lights_spotlight

https://jsfiddle.net/4to72rkn/

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, cube, cubeM, terrain, spot;


scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 400 / 300, 0.01, 10000);
camera.position.set(600, 0, 5000);
scene.add(camera);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setClearColor (0xdddddd, 1)
renderer.setSize(400, 300);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

container = document.getElementById('canv_0')
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

cubeM = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
});

cube = new THREE.Mesh(
new THREE.CubeGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000), cubeM);
cube.position.set(0, 0, 0);
cube.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
cube.castShadow = true;
scene.add(cube);


terrain = new THREE.Mesh(
new THREE.CubeGeometry(10000, 1000, 10000), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
}));
terrain.receiveShadow = true;
terrain.position.set(0, -2000, 0);
terrain.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);

scene.add(terrain);

spot = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
spot.shadow.camera.near = 1000;
spot.shadow.camera.far = 10000;
spot.castShadow = true;
spot.position.set(-1000, 2000, 1500);
spot.distance = 20000;
spot.penumbra = 1;
scene.add(spot);
scene.add (new THREE.CameraHelper(spot.shadow.camera));

(function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.js"></script>
<div id="canv_0" width="400" height="300">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was keep investigating and I can made it just like you. Seems like spot.distance was not set correctly. But CameraHelper for the spot.shadow.camera is bad (the frustum is incorrect). Instead, if we use SpotLightHelper(spot) the shadow light's frustum is right (can be this a bug?)